# Manipulating 2 dimensional string array with some special conditions

Tags: java, arrays

I am processing a large amount of data which comes via csv file, and getting as an 2 dimensional array in that a specific column (say last column) as multiple values. Need to duplicate the same row with the values except the multiple valued column which should be separated as below. (order of the Row doesn't matter)

```
Row 1 -->{hi, good, morning}
Row 2 -->{hi, good, afternoon}
```

***Sample input (2D string array):***

```
String[][] masterArray = {
                {"hi", "good", "morning,afternoon"},
                {"have a", "nice", "day,trip,journey"},
                {"hi", "good", "evening"},
                {"I", "love", "you,India"},
                {"enjoy", "your", "dinner"}
        };
```

***Expected output (2D string array):***

```
            String[][] masterOutput = {
                    {"hi", "good", "morning"},
                    {"hi", "good", "afternoon"},
                    {"have a", "nice", "day"},
                    {"have a", "nice", "trip"},
                    {"have a", "nice", "journey"},
                    {"hi", "good", "evening"},
                    {"I", "love", "you"},
                    {"I", "love", "India"},
                    {"Enjoy", "your", "dinner"},
        };
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: What approach have you tried?

Comment: I have tried as below,
a. converted masterArray into list of single dimensional array
b. tried using the contains(",") and split() - to locate the required element
c. iterated masterList and found the indices to be removed and added into separeate list

I am stuck with duplicating the current row which contains the morning,afternoon or so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your solution:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MyClass {

    public static String[][] expandColumn(String[][] masterArray) {
        List<String[]> masterOutputList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < masterArray.length; i++) {
            String itemToExpand = masterArray[i][masterArray[i].length - 1];
            String[] parts = itemToExpand.split(",");
            for (int j = 0; j < parts.length; j++) {
                String[] row = new String[masterArray[i].length];
                System.arraycopy(masterArray[i], 0, row, 0, masterArray[i].length - 1);
                row[row.length - 1] = parts[j];
                masterOutputList.add(row);
            }
        }
        return masterOutputList.toArray(new String[0][0]);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] masterArray = {
                {"hi", "good", "morning,afternoon"},
                {"have a", "nice", "day,trip,journey"},
                {"hi", "good", "evening"},
                {"I", "love", "you,India"},
                {"enjoy", "your", "dinner"}
        };
        String[][] ss = expandColumn(masterArray);
        for (int i = 0; i < ss.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < ss[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(ss[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know exactly how many columns you should have. This can be done with a double for loop. Iterate over every row, inside that loop, make a new Array for every string in the multi value column. Add this to an arraylist. At the end. Convert the arraylist to an Array.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a 'one-liner' approach using Java 8 streams:

```
Arrays.stream(masterArray)
        .flatMap(row -> Arrays.stream(row[row.length - 1].split(","))
                    .map(newRowTerminator -> {
                        final String[] fullNewRow = row.clone();
                        fullNewRow[row.length - 1] = newRowTerminator;
                        return fullNewRow;
                    })
        )
        .toArray(String[][]::new);
```

Comment: Why the downvote here?  This answer satisfies all the requirements laid out in the question

Comment: I have not down voted,  I am new to java8 , unable to get the output printed for masterArray, please explain.

Comment: This simply returns a new `String[][]`, for example: `String[][] masterOutput = Arrays.stream(...`.  To print a 2D array of strings, you can use `System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(masterOutput));`

Answer (score 0):

I've already posted an [answer using streams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44178312/1813169), but here's a lower-level method which *may or may not* be more performant - I don't have time to run benchmarks right now.

```
int newRowsRequired = 0;

for (final String[] row : masterArray) {
    final String rowTerminators = row[row.length - 1];
    newRowsRequired += rowTerminators.length() - rowTerminators.replace(",", "").length() + 1;
}

final String[][] outArray = new String[newRowsRequired][];

int currentRow = 0;

for (final String[] row : masterArray) {
    for (final String rowTerminator : row[row.length - 1].split(",")) {
        final String[] newRow = row.clone();
        newRow[row.length - 1] = rowTerminator;
        outArray[currentRow++] = newRow;
    }
}
```